# SQL: Replacing rows in a table using the rows in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL question.

I have two tables: tableA and tableB. These two tables has exactly the same structure (simplified version):

```
rowid : big int
name: character varying
enabled : boolean
```

The two table:

```
tableA contains all the data and their enabled columns are all true.
tableB contains data in tableA that should be turned off (enabled set to false).
```

My question is that how can I write a SQL statement that replacing all the rows in tableA with the row in tableB (or similarly, set the enabled field to false for all the rows that exists in tableB)

I use PostgreSQL. SQL statement from other SQL types are also welcome.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.
Try:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Enabled = false
WHERE rowid IN
(SELECT rowid FROM TableB)
```

Comment: @KZhang Note that `IN (SELECT...)` scales poorly with significant numbers of results - it gets quite slow. You're better off using a join update with `UPDATE ... FROM`; see Erwin's answer. Also beware of how `IN` behaves with nulls.

Answer (score 3):

This would do (but syntax is compatible with MSSQL, thx @ comments):

```
update tableA
   set tableA.enabled = false
from tableA
    inner join tableB on tableA.rowid = tableB.rowid
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL, you cannot table-qualify columns in the `SET` clause. Also, there is no need to add `tableA` a second time in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: No need to add tableA in the FROM clause a second time unless you want to use an outer or join, yeah. No progress on support for `UPDATE ... FROM OUTER JOIN` or equivalent yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tbl_a a
SET    enabled = FALSE
FROM   tbl_b b
WHERE  a.rowid = b.rowid
AND    a.enabled IS NOT FALSE;
```

If `enabled` is defined `NOT NULL` simplify to:

```
AND a.enabled;
```

- @kuba posted a similar approach, but his syntax is not working in PostgreSQL. Refer to the [current PostgreSQL manual about `UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html) for details. I quote:

> Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target
>   column — for example, `UPDATE tab SET tab.col` = 1 is invalid.

- In PostgreSQL, joining in another table to an `UPDATE` statement with a **`FROM`** clause is not just more elegant, it is also faster than using `IN (subselect)`. Hardly matters with small updates, but can get substantial with big ones. Test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html).
- And last but not least, for any RDBMS: **avoid empty updates**. Don't apply the update if the row in table A is already turned off. It will not change the data, but still create a dead row, may cause triggers to fire and cost performance and disc space.